# Writing kernel module(s) for a multi-function i2c device - one or many?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, i2c

I have an i2c device, built into the board I am developing for.  It responds to a single address, but the first byte (sometimes called "command" or "register") dictates the function addressed.

I can use the device from userspace with `i2cset/get/detect`, so I know that everything is working.

The device controls LEDs (and so should appear in `/sys/class/leds`).

It also has GPIO (and so should appear in `/sys/class/gpio`).

There are a further half-dozen different places where parts of the device's functionality should appear.

Should I code this as:

1. One i2c client module, and find a way to get things listed in the right places in `/sys`.
2. One platform module and many driver modules, all sharing the single i2c device (somehow) with their module code in function-specific places.

(This is my first kernel module since late-2.4 or early-2.6, it was a long time ago.)

Comment: It's hard for me fine tune to post in answer section. Before that, will it be possible for you to share the device name/number which you are going to use? To answer your question, yes you need to write the driver for the device itself in according layer. Example, write the led driver in linux/driver/leds/. As led itself exports the class /sys/class/leds, you may need to understand led core layers and write on top of it. I will be able to answer specific if I know the device itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux sources take a look at wm8350 module. It consist of one core module bound to i2c bus and many child platform modules that uses core module API to access chip registers.

Core module consist of:

- [drivers/mfd/wm8350-i2c.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-i2c.c) - bind wm8350 to i2c bus
- [drivers/mfd/wm8350-core.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-core.c) - create child platform devices and provide API for child devices

GPIO module consist of:

- [drivers/gpio/gpio-wm8350.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-wm8350.c)

During core module initialization [wm8350_i2c_probe()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-i2c.c#L26) get called. It calls [wm8350_device_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-core.c#L276). It create child platform devices using [wm8350_client_dev_register()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-core.c#L254).

Child module [drivers/gpio/gpio-wm8350.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-wm8350.c) registers as module for "platform:wm8350-gpio" and it's entry point is [wm8350_gpio_probe()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-wm8350.c#L107).

In order to get access to core module, GPIO module do:

```
107 static int wm8350_gpio_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
108 {
109         struct wm8350 *wm8350 = dev_get_drvdata(pdev->dev.parent);
```

And then it calls something like

```
36         return wm8350_set_bits(wm8350, WM8350_GPIO_CONFIGURATION_I_O,
37                                1 << offset);
```

Comment: In http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-core.c?v=4.4#L276 where does the `struct wm8350` get created?  How does the kernel know to call `wm8350_device_init` with a pointer to it?  (I've previously used the  `module_init` macro in other modules and had not encountered `xxx_device_init` with arguments.)

Comment: Don't worry about the comment above.  I was under the false impression that wm8350_core was the one which would be "init'ed" and start the others.  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-i2c.c?v=4.4#L48 shows that its the wm8350-i2c module that is responsible for "init'ing" the wm8350-core module.